# How do I add login/logout links to navigation in specific position

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to add login/logout links to main navigation menu and I did it as follow:

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_login_logout_link', 10, 2);
function add_login_logout_link($items, $args) {
        ob_start();
        wp_loginout('index.php');
        $loginoutlink = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        $items .= '<li>'. $loginoutlink .'</li>';
    return $items;
}
```

That works but add links to the end and I need to add in the 2nd position for example, how I do that?

Comment: Use http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_loginout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_login_logout_link', 10, 2);
function add_login_logout_link($items, $args) {
    ob_start();
    wp_loginout('index.php');
    $loginoutlink = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    $mylink.= '<li>'. $loginoutlink .'</li>';
    array_splice( $items, 1, 0, $mylink);

return $items;
}
```